# What website to use to find data for my highschool project on BMI and Covid deaths?

Tags: data-request, covid19

Im doing an assessment for my highschool project where I need to find data for BMI and number of covid deaths associated with that BMI. Is there any website that will give me just the raw numbers on a table or anything like that?

Comment: This study just came out: https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/volumes/70/wr/mm7010e4.htm and press coverage: https://www.nytimes.com/2021/03/08/health/coronavirus-obesity-weight.html

Answer (score 0):

good question.

There are some sources linked here, for China, and also for early in the pandemic: https://ourworldindata.org/mortality-risk-covid#case-fatality-rate-of-covid-19-by-preexisting-health-conditions

but BMI isn't directly reported. (indicators of BMI are, though, for example: heart disease, diabetes, hypertension)

[image: health conditions for covid deaths]

Are any of those useful? If so, you can find the data here: https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/tree/master/public/data